# Is this property for $\mathbb{R}^2$ true?

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to see if the following statement holds:

> There exists some $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ which is not in in a oine of the form $y=\lambda x$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $(a,b)$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the line $y=Nx$ intersects $U$.

But I don't know if for every point of that form we can choose a radius $r$ small enough to make the open ball $B_r(a)$ not intersect any line, or if for every radius $r$, we can take $N$ big enough so that the line $y=Nx$ intersects the open ball centered at $a$. I think that if the statement is true, the point $(a,b)$ must have an $x$ coordinate close to zero, but so far I have not been able to prove it.

Comment: Take $(0, 0)$. $\phantom{ }$

Comment: @anomaly Sorry, I meant a point that is not already in a line of the form $y=\lambda x$. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Take $(0,1)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(a,b)=(0,1)$. Clearly it cannot be on a line with your prescribed form, but any neighborhood $U$ of this point contains a point $(\frac{1}{N},1)$ for $N$ big enough.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I convinced myself that the $y$ axis was a line of that form.

Comment: By the way I'm pretty sure you were right : any such point must have $a=0$.